# Jenkins login page is not loading

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, ubuntu-20.04

I tried to visit http://localhost:8080 but when I visit this url, it reloads after every 3-4 seconds but it doesn't show login page.
I am using ubuntu 20.04
Please anyone help me with this issue.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your Jenkins service probably has a problem to start up.

You can check the service logs to identify the error. As mentioned in [Jenkins docs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/viewing-logs/#linux), this is where you can find the logs:

> By default logs should be made available in `/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log`

Comment: If you have trouble identifying/solving the issues, please edit your question and add the logs and I'll try to assist.